# "On a side note" vs. "by the way"

Tags: differences, expressions, discourse-markers

What's the difference between "on a side note" and "by the way"?
Is one of them restricted to certain situations while the other is not?

Answer (score 7):

*By the way* may bring up a new major topic — related to the previous one. You may shift the whole conversation into a new direction, and keep it on that new topic for a while, drilling it thoroughly.

*On a side note* should be just a small side note — similarly you shift the subject somewhat, but you just drop a small bit of information and you're either back to the previous topic or ending the conversation.

Other than that, you'll see the two in somewhat different contexts. You'll rarely hear someone asking a question "on a side note", while "and by the way, did you...?" style questions are very common. "By the way" is more informal, commonly appearing in day-to-day speech, while "on a side note" would be something to be seen more in more formal contexts.

Comment: Wow - subsubsets. Pragmatic markers subset reorientation markers subsubsets major and minor!

Comment: Adding to this, "*on* a side note" is not that common to begin with (cf. WS2's answer) — "*as* a side note" is more common, and "as an aside" is more common still. COCA has 7, 20, and 115 cites, respectively. BNC has 0, 0, and 18.

Comment: As an aside, here are the sources of @RegDwigнt's numbers above: https://corpus.byu.edu/COCA/ & https://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/ for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across 'on a side note'.

I think 'incidentally' is a good word to use for an aside.

During a conversation between two lawyers, let's say about someone's willingness to give evidence in court, one of them might say: 'Did you know, incidentally, that he has a criminal record?'.

Or with a doctor, when discussing feeling unwell, 'I have, incidentally, just returned from a journey up the Amazon in a rowing boat'.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+side+note&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20side%20note%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @mplungjan Who are the people who use it? How is it that I don't hear it? I read a great deal, including newspapers like the Guardian and Independent, and listen to BBC Radio 4. I watched Question Time last night with David Dimbleby. I didn't hear him say 'on a side note'! Nor Professor David Starkey, Tessa Jowell nor George Galloway! You hear all kinds of things in the crowd at a football match, but I don't include them in the lexicon of good English.

Comment: _Richard Coutice is a Senior Studio Manager and Digital Operations Specialist at the BBC:_ "***On a side note***, I also noticed that the clouds are the fluffy, Cumulus kind. The ones that make you think of a blue sky, a refreshing breeze and clean air. The sort of clouds that the Orb wrote about. But, I've been around for a while and I often suspect that Cumulonimbus might be more appropriate - dark, thunderous and anvil shaped, ready to dump on you from a great height, like the endlessly doomed Wile E. Coyote of the Roadrunner cartoons. ..... But I digress."

Comment: _Jon Donnison - BBC Sydney correspondent_: "***On a side note***, this "election bingo" from the Guardian is well worth a look and might liven up viewing"

Comment: Independent News > Business > Business Comment
Mark Leftly: "***On a side note***, it shows how dangerous the bank levy is to the regions. It should not be glibly praised as part of a wider clampdown on fat cats in Canary Wharf and the Square Mile."

Comment: @mplungjan They probably say 'awesome' as well! It sounds like one of those phrases which which has become a refuge for those of limited vocabulary. If you want to hear proper English listen to, or better still read the history books, of  Professor David Starkey. Cantankerous old blighter he might be when he starts talking about the definition of 'rape', but he knows how to use the language.

Comment: @mplungjan I used your book.google.com.ngrams thing to test 'away the lads'. It produced a result of 12 per 100 million (whatever that means). That is about one ninth the number of 'on a side note'. But given that there can't be more than a million Geordies who use it, it either demonstrates that there are less than 10 million people in the Anglosphere saying 'on a side note' or else it is less frequently employed by those who use it  than there are Geordies who say 'away the lads' - which is excellent dialect but not the Queen's English.

Comment: My posts were just to show that the expression exists and is in use.

Answer (score -2):

> By the way, do you have any idea where my mackintosh is? I've looked everywhere.
>   By the way, I expect my bike back or somebody's photo is about to get destroyed.
>   By the way, I need my pen back.
>
> On a side note, I've found my mackintosh.
>   On a side note, can I borrow your bike?
>   On a side note, do you have any idea when the party is?
>
> On a side note, can I have a bite of that chocolate cake? It looks awfully good.

Comment: I'm afraid but this is not helpful at all.